# Default Select Option is Multiple Select is not visibly selected. (VueJs3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have created a Select Option, in which one option is by default selected. In example one below, the default selected option is visibly selected within the select bar before opening it.

```
<select v-model="formData.replyMethod">
 <option value="" selected {{ $t(`files.homeName`)}}</option> # This is visibly selected
 <option value="1" selected {{ $t(`files.foo`)}}</option>
 <option value="2" selected {{ $t(`files.bar`)}}</option>
</select>
```

However when moving to a Computed Property & V-For, the selected option is selected, but not visibly (you have to open the list to see that now), in its place is a blank bar.

What is causing the difference in output between these two ways of creating a list?

Example 2:

```
<select v-model="formData.replyMethod">
        <option v-bind:value="selectedOption.id" selected>{{ $t(selectedOption.name) }}</option>
        <option v-bind:value="selectOpts.id" v-for="selectOpt in selectOpts">{{ $t(selectOpt.name) }}</option>
        </select>

const selectedOption = computed(() => {
  if(fooBarVariable) {
    let opt =  {id: 1, name: 'Foo'};
    return opt
  }
});

const selectOpts = [{ id: null, name: 'files.placeholder'},{id: 1, name: 'files.reply'},{id: 2, name: 'files.example'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using v-model with select input, don't use selected attribute to set a default value for your select input.

If you're setting the value for each option by `selectedOption.id` then simply type the id of the option you would like it to be visible in `formData.replyMethod`.

For example:

```js
const selectOpts = [{ id: 1, name: 'files.placeholder'}];

const formData =  {
    replyMethod: 1,
};
```

```html
<select v-model="formData.replyMethod">
  <option v-for="option in selectOpts" :value="option.id">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This will set an initial value for your input on component mount which will be overridden upon the user action (Same behavior as `selected` attribute)